# Object Tag and IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I've come across an interesting problem with IE9 and object tags.

In the simplest form for a client I am hosting a website (ASP .NET Web Forms site) within an object tag from a page in a separate website, for reasons that are ridiculous and mind blowing, the html looks like the following:

```
    <object id="so" data="https://so.com/so" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"> 

    </object>
```

In Chrome and Firefox when I click a link in the html inside the object tag, the browser tab has a  loading icon (as per a normal page event) giving the user feedback that an event has occurred. In IE 9 this does not occur so the user doesn't know that clicking the link has fired any events.

I've looked at the onbeforeunload event of the object tag with no success, for instance:

```
    <object id="so" data="https://so.com/so" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" onBeforeOnLoad="javascript: onDocumentUnLoad();"> 

    </object>
```

Using the above method the onbeforeunload function is not called.

I also tried using a ajax load via jQuery into a div but handling out of context css and js references and post-backs become unmanageable and also adding click events to every button or href affected performance and functionality.

I was was wondering if there's another approach to give the user feedback or a simple workaround.

Comment: I see you've already done some experimenting ;) So, it didn't work using `iframe` either?

Comment: Not working in IFRAME either. Still trying to work it out myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that works.

In the parent page create an handler for a custom event. In this case "unloadingChild":

```
//using jQuery 1.4.2
$("body").bind("unloadingChild", function(){
    console.log("child unloaded");
});
```

In the child hosted page trigger the custom event via the body unload event:
    //body element unload
    $(window).unload(bodyUnload());
    function bodyUnload(){
        //trigger the parent unloadingChild event
        parent.$("body").trigger("unloadingChild");
    }

I don't know if it's the best way but it seems like a good way. That certainly works for this scenario.

It doesn't solve the object unload but it gets around the problem.

This will only work for two websites with the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Otherwise you will get an error similar to "*Permission denied to access property '$'*"